# Zend framework router 404 error

Tags: php, zend-framework

Here is my zend framework module config:

```
 'routes' => [

            'home' => [
                'type' => Literal::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],

            'default' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                    'constraints' => [
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    ]
                ),
            )
...  
 'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
        ],
```

and my IndexController.php looks like this:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }

    public function testAction()
    {
        echo 1;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I want get a right response when I access `http://host/Index/test`, but now I get a `404 error` and a description like:

> "The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class ...".

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `'type' => 'segment'` to `'type' => 'Segment'`